# Any aircraft that can takeoff or land on 150 m / 500 ft runway?

Tags: landing, takeoff, runways

Just spotted on [Google Maps](https://goo.gl/maps/hk6BYivUfmVgQAs1A):

[image]

What could be the purpose for building a 150 m / 500 ft runway?

I understand that no regular aircraft can takeoff or land on such distance, so certainly the reason isn't GA. In the same time, isn't this a way too long as for flying models?

Comment: Try Google translate on "club aeromodelisme".

Comment: https://arcsantcugat.com/el-video-del-arc/ , https://arcsantcugat.com/avions/ , https://arcsantcugat.com/galeries-dimatges/videos/

Comment: Interesting that no one has yet mentioned the "X"s on the runway, visible here https://arcsantcugat.com/el-video-del-arc/ .  These are relatively common features of rc runways, especially the larger ones.  On the other hand, it's a bit odd that they would paint the heading-based runway numbers on the ends of the runway (visible at same link).  I guess they just want their runway to be really, really scale-like-- *not* normally an objective in these situations!

Comment: @Sanchises And exactly HOW translating model airplanes club's name will bring me closer into answering my question -- if the depicted runway isn't long big as for models? Thanks for your comment, pity it is pointless.

Comment: @quietflyer Please, see my comment above. I welcome all the feedback. As long as it has any value, meaning or sense.

Comment: Steve Henry might beg to differ: https://youtu.be/zk4teJwQ6FI  (skip to 4:00 if you’re in a hurry)

Comment: Please review StackExchange rules and policies.  People asking questions are generally expected to *show an effort* that they tried to work the question themselves and got stuck.  Given the close resemblance between French and English on that particular phrase, *at least* a pass through Google Translate was called for.  Rudeness to your peers is also against the rules here.

Comment: I used to fly a Rallye Minerva that could land or take off in around 100m. I often flew from fields and strips that were being worked on. I am sure most Cubs could do that in less.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I understand and strictly try to follow all the SO and cultural rules. I was just a little bit tired reading all comments telling me "check the club name", where in fact knowing the club name brings me even an inch closer into answering my question: "Can any GA take-off from such a short runway and if such runway isn't too long for model airplanes". I am incorrect then please, point me to any comment (not mentioning very accurate Pondlife's answer) that brings any value here or try to answer my question directly.

Comment: @copper.hat That's the answer I was looking for. Thank you for bringing an actual airplanes family name for airplanes that could possibly land or take-off at a such short distance. Maybe you could craft that comment into an answer, so I can at least upvote it. Thank you for not being another person here who thinks that translating runway owner's name is anything close into answering this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [club's website](https://arcsantcugat.com) has some more information (emphasis mine):

> Hi ha moltes coses que marquen la diferència en l’ARC però la seva
> magnífica pista de 150 metres és una cosa que no deixa indiferent als
> que visiten el club.
>
> Totalment asfaltada, amb indicacions d’aproximació, carrils i **ample
> suficient com per aterrar el més gran dels aeromodels**.

Roughly translated: "more than adequate for landing the largest model aircraft".

Some model aircraft are very large indeed (Google "giant scale RC planes"); one company's [site says](https://www.horizonhobby.com/airplanes/by-size/giant-scale/):

> Giant Scale radio control airplanes have a minimum wingspan of eighty
> inches for single-wing airplanes, and a minimum wingspan of 60 inches
> for multi-wing airplanes.

It's easy to see why such a large model aircraft would need plenty of room. But there might be other reasons, even with smaller models. It would allow more people to operate at the same time, which could be important for a club with a lot of active members.

And finally, there are plenty of GA STOL aircraft that can take off and land in [much less than 500'](https://www.aopa.org/news-and-media/all-news/2018/may/17/valdez-stol-distances-get-shorter). It wouldn't allow much margin for error (especially considering the trees all around that particular runway) so it might not be safe and/or practical unless the conditions are good, but it is *possible*.

Answer (score 3):

While we've established that this field was built for model aircraft, there are a number of piloted aircraft that can make use of a runway this short.

A general class of STOL (Short TakeOff and Landing) aircraft includes many that can, if lightly loaded or with sufficient headwind, land and take off in this distance.  Additionally, many if not most ultralights require very little runway due to their low stall speed and propellers optimized for low-speed thrust to avoid exceeding level flight speed limitations.

Answer (score 1):

> isn't this a way too long as for flying models

Google "pylon racer landing" -- here's a start --

-- now imagine that happening on a hard surface-- might take some room to stop!

Answer (score 0):

The club’s website seems fairly clear that it’s for model aircraft https://arcsantcugat.com/

Comment: Which doesn't say anything about if runway length isn't to long for models.

Comment: The OP asks the purpose and that is the purpose.  “I can’t land there, the runway is too long” said no pilot ever.